# Problemas con obtener archivos creados en Swift 2

Tags: ios, swift2, xcode

Estoy guardando una imagen en un directorio pero cuando voy a acceder a ella me devuelve que no existe el archivo y revisando la ruta encuentro que parte de ella cambia cada vez que accedo a la ruta adjunto ejemplo:

/Users/mac/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/B378CE15-4E91-4EA1-9DDD-FCD5DC9D8190/data/Containers/Data/Application/**21C7E4D9-B138-44C2-80BB-2B431056C0EE**/Documents/TMGProfileImage/663565364763465.jpg

/Users/mac/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/B378CE15-4E91-4EA1-9DDD-FCD5DC9D8190/data/Containers/Data/Application/**EEE47491-8D09-40FB-ADBE-78E7B1F83674**/Documents/TMGProfileImage/663565364763465.jpg

¿Qué debo de hacer en este caso para que no se pierda el archivo?

Gracias

Comment: ¿Puedes añadir el código que estás utilizando para acceder a esos archivos?

Answer (score 1):

Agrega la imagen en el Assets. así Xcode genera una copia en el directorio del proyecto además Xcode luego puede acceder a esa imagen solo nombrandola sin tener que especificar formato.

Comment: El problema es que la imagen es descargada de un servicio web

Comment: @Andres, ese es un detalle importante.. Entre restarts del simulador, se crea otra carpeta para la aplicación y a la vez, la carpeta `Documents` (que está adentro). Si necesitas persistir una imagen entre restarts, podes user `NSUserDefaults` (fácil) o Core Data (un poco más complicado).

Answer (score 0):

Mira lo que pasa es que guardas la ruta completo y NUNCA tienes que hacer eso porque el Documents Directory cambia. Lo que tienes que hacer es solo guardar el nombre de tu archivo y concatenarlo a la ruta de Documents cada que accedas a el.

Por ejemplo:

Guardas solamente: "TMGProfileImage/663565364763465.jpg"

y cuando quieras acceder a la imagen concatenas el documentsDirectory con tu ruta:

documentsDirectory()+"TMGProfileImage/663565364763465.jpg"

```
func documentsDirectory() -> String {
    let paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.DocumentDirectory, .UserDomainMask, true)
    let documentsDirectory = paths[0]
    return documentsDirectory
}
```